# How to add the GlobalTrafficShapingHandler before HttpDecompressor

Tags: java, reactor-netty

I want to calculate the compressed size before HttpDecompressor.

I try to call `connection.addHandlerFirst`, but does not work.

```java
HttpClient.create()
    .mapConnect((connection, bootstrap) -> connection.map(
        conn -> {
            conn.addHandlerFirst(new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                    if (msg instanceof HttpContent) {
                        System.out.println("received:" + msg);
                    }
                    super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                }
            });
            return conn;
        }
    ))
    .compress(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Connection#addHandlerFirst` won't help because the handler will be added after reactor codecs. [More information here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/Connection.html#addHandlerFirst-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler-)

You can add this handler directly to the Netty pipeline like this:

```
HttpClient.create()
        .mapConnect((connection, bootstrap) -> connection.map(
                conn -> {
                    conn.channel().pipeline().addBefore(NettyPipeline.HttpDecompressor, "myhandler",new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                            if (msg instanceof HttpContent) {
                                System.out.println("received:" + msg);
                            }
                            super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                        }
                    });
                    return conn;
                }
        ))
    .compress(true);
```

However you should remember that once you add this directly to the pipeline, if you use connection pooling this handler will stay also for the next requests (which is not the case with `Connection#addHandlerFirst`). So if you need this only for particular requests, then you should remove it after the response is received.
Something like this:

```
HttpClient.create()
        .doOnResponse((res, conn) ->
                    conn.channel().pipeline().addBefore(NettyPipeline.HttpDecompressor, "myhandler",new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
                            if (msg instanceof HttpContent) {
                                System.out.println("received:" + msg);
                            }
                            super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
                        }
                    }))
        .doAfterResponse((res, conn) ->
                    conn.channel().pipeline().remove("myhandler"))
        .compress(true)
```